# Split two columns into specific width percentages using SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

So I have been struggling on this for some time now, so I wanted to reach out and see if someone might be able to assist me.

So I have the following code:

```
HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Location")
            .font(.callout.weight(.semibold))
            .lineLimit(1)
        if item.address != "" {
            Group {
                Text(item.address)
                Text(item.city + ", " + item.state)
            }
            .font(.footnote)
            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
        } else {
            Text("N/A")
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    VStack {
        HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Weather")
                    .font(.subheadline.weight(.semibold))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                HStack(spacing: 3) {
                    Image(systemName: "waveform")
                        .imageScale(.small)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Text("79%")
                        .font(.caption.weight(.regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Reviews")
                    .font(.subheadline.weight(.semibold))
                    .lineLimit(1)
                HStack(spacing: 3) {
                    Image(systemName: "star")
                        .imageScale(.small)
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    Text("4.7 (1212)")
                        .font(.caption.weight(.regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                }
            }
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
        }
    }
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
    .border(.red)
}
```

Which outputs two main `50%/50% VStack` columns:

[image]

What is the best way to have the two main `VStack` use `30%/70%`?

I would like to have the first `VStack` be `30%` of the screen view, then the second `VStack` be `70%` of the screen view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GeometryReader` to get the width of the main `HStack` and set the width of the child `VStack`s to a percentage of the width which can be accessed through `GeometryReader`

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
                firstVStack
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.3)
                secondVStack
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.7)
            }
        }
    }

    private var firstVStack: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Location")
                .font(.callout.weight(.semibold))
                .lineLimit(1)
            if item.address != "" {
                Group {
                    Text(item.address)
                    Text(item.city + ", " + item.state)
                }
                .font(.footnote)
                .foregroundColor(.secondary)
            } else {
                Text("N/A")
            }
        }
    }

    private var secondVStack: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 3) {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Weather")
                        .font(.subheadline.weight(.semibold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    HStack(spacing: 3) {
                        Image(systemName: "waveform")
                            .imageScale(.small)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Text("79%")
                            .font(.caption.weight(.regular))
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Reviews")
                        .font(.subheadline.weight(.semibold))
                        .lineLimit(1)
                    HStack(spacing: 3) {
                        Image(systemName: "star")
                            .imageScale(.small)
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                        Text("4.7 (1212)")
                            .font(.caption.weight(.regular))
                            .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
                .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Chris, this works well for the width, but it looks like the height gets completely destroyed and now the other views I have below, just overlap this view, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: You could place the views below inside the GeometryReader

Comment: Thanks Chris, I'll check it out later today!